# T-SQL Exec statement syntax error

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Why is the first statement a syntax error?

```
-- this does not work: "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'system_user'"
exec dbo.spEmployee_GetRecords @pLoginName = system_user

-- this works
declare @p nvarchar(30);
select @p=system_user
exec dbo.spEmployee_GetRecords @pLoginName = @p
```

(SQL Server 2005 Express Edition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the syntax of `EXECUTE`. You can only pass values or variables, not functions or expressions. See [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) on BOL.

Comment: You are right. The similarity to function calls in $(insert-any-programming-language) misled me. I wonder about the underlying design decision...